# overlapping divs within flex child

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to position some `div`s on top of each other (i.e., overlapping) within a `div` that is a child flex element. I guess a js fiddle would help:

https://jsfiddle.net/498xpp6n/12/

The `#m1` and `#m2` divs should appear on top of each other and take up the whole space of the `#mainpanel` div. (In this example the text 'Mainpanel1 ...' and 'Mainpanel2 ...' should appear on top of each other.) If possible, this should be done without referencing the sizes of external elements, as the layout is dynamic (as can be seen in the fiddle).

I tried using `position: absolute`, but then they are no longer positioned relative to their parent. I've tried various other approaches but none has been successful. (I suppose I could list them, but as they were unsuccessful they would only be unnecessary clutter.)

Comment: Do ***"various other approaches"*** include *"negative margins"*? As a side note, i'm a "various other approaches" man myself. I use it **all the time**. For everything! I can never get enough of *various other approaches*.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Andrei. I could use negative margins for #m2, but only if I know how tall its parent (and sibling) is. Or is there another way to go about this?

Comment: Overlapping elements in normal flow can be done via negative margin on either element (usually on the one that is creating the "need" for overlapping.

Comment: transform ? https://jsfiddle.net/498xpp6n/13/

Comment: @GCyrillus would this work if we had more than 2 children?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu try it and see if that method suits you, but maybe that already was one of the various approach ;)

Comment: I tried a `height: 100%;` with a negative `margin-top`, but that last property is (when using a percentage) linked to the *width* and not the *height* of the container; see https://jsfiddle.net/498xpp6n/14/

Comment: @GCyrillus, thanks for your suggestion. I didn't use transform in my various other approaches yet. I've edited your changes here: https://jsfiddle.net/498xpp6n/15/ and it looks good - but the container now has an increased height. I suppose I could use `overflow: hidden`, but I'd like to understand what's going on there. Any idea?

Comment: Elrudi, what do you mean by "on top of each other"? Do you want the two items to fill up the container vertically and each of them have 50% of the parent height?

Comment: transform only move or transform  the element at screen, but room and initial size used remain the same (just like relative) .

Comment: I meant that the divs occupy the same rectangle of screen real estate

Comment: And do they have the same height at all times?

Comment: Yes. Their left, right, top, and bottom sides line up (as well as with the container, ideally)

Comment: In that case **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/498xpp6n/18/)** is your answer. And it has absolutely nothing to do with flexbox. The `display` property of the parent is completely irrelevant and misleading here.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, that's exactly what I wanted. I mentioned the flexbox in order to make sure it was clear those child divs were not at a fixed position. When using `position: absolute` they'd leave their parent (graphically). Thanks for clearing up that using `absolute` inside `relative` takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

if you use flex, you need to go all the way with display and flex value:

example with transform and **`overflow:hidden;` has to be used  because `#m2` is not absolute**...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#outer-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
#inner-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
}
#header {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
#mainpanel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 3;
  background: rgba(200, 222, 123, 0.6);
  overflow: hidden;
}
#m1 {
  background: rgba(123, 222, 200, 0.3);
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#m2 {
  background: rgba(222, 125, 200, 0.3);
  transform: translatey(-100%);
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius:2em;
}
#m1,
#m2 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;/* ? maube useful */
}
#aside {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: orange;
}
#footer {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #inner-flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #mainpanel {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  #aside {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-flex-container">

  <div id="header">The Header The Header The Header The Header</div>

  <div id="inner-flex-container">
    <div id="mainpanel">
      <div id="m1">
        Mainpanel1 Mainpanel1 Mainpanel1 Mainpanel1
      </div>
      <div id="m2">
        Mainpanel2 Mainpanel2 Mainpanel2 Mainpanel2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="aside">
      settings settings settings settings settings settings settings settings settings ter
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">The Footer The Footer The Footer The Fooner-flex-containe
  </div>
</div>
```

added inset shadows of 2 different size to show where m1 & m2 are standing